# Como ejecutar correctamente mi servidor Express Node en AWS Ec2?

Tags: nodejs, express, aws, ec2

espero se encuentren bien.

Tengo un inconveniente con una **instancia Ec2** la cual tiene Linux instalado, tiene NodeJs versión 18, ya el proyecto cargado e instalado todas sus dependencias, los grupos de seguridad todos apuntan su TPC al puerto que solicita **Express**, ejecuto el proyecto desde **SSH Putty** dando como resultado que mi servidor se conecta y lista todas las solicitudes desde el puerto asignado. Pero cuando ingreso desde la **IP o DNS publico** en ese puerto me arroja: **Error de Conexión y luego La pagina no responde.**

Mi código del index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on("stream", (image) =>{
    socket.broadcast.emit("stream", image);
});
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Ando algo preocupado porque por más que investigo e integro no procede a mostrar respuesta mi aplicación NodeJs. **Además soy principiante en NodeJs y el uso de AWS**. Espero puedan ayudarme y muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Está raro, con el grupo de seguridad habilitado a TPC con el puerto 3000 deberías llegar. que status code te arroja al solicitar la petición ?

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges) podrás dejar comentarios. Lee [answer].